# Making the Event Registration icon larger

Tags: civievent

How do I make registration icon on an event page larger? Is seems to be a bit small and is it possible to move it around?

Comment: Do you mean the button with Register Now text?

Answer (score 2):

You need to start from a basic familiarity with how to style webpages. I suggest googling a few simple tutorials on css.